Spotbugs issue with Java 17
I am using spotbugs in my grails application with Java 11 and it is working fine. But when I upgraded to Java 17 it is causing error. I even tried using spotbugs version which is compatible with Java 17.
Getting following error (same with spotbugsTest and spotbugsMain) -

Task :spotbugsIntegrationTest
The following errors occurred during analysis:
Error scanning com/myProject/gradle/BaseGradleIntegrationTest for referenced classes

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
      At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.<init>(FBClassReader.java:35)


  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:48)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:34)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:261)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:75)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:261)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.buildReferencedClassSet(FindBugs2.java:806)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:249) 

I tried hard to look for solutions but none can solve this issue. Some of them are https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/1718  and https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/1570
Here's my build.gradle configuration for spotbugs -
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'groovy'
  id 'idea'
  id 'maven-publish'
  id 'com.github.spotbugs' version '4.5.0'
  id 'com.github.ben-manes.versions' version '0.42.0'
}
tasks.withType(com.github.spotbugs.snom.SpotBugsTask) {
    reports {
      xml.enabled = false
      html.enabled = true
    }
  }


toolsVersion added in global-config.gradle -
spotbugs {
    toolVersion = '4.2.2'
}

Please help me out with this. I tried many versions of spotbugs.

not sure why it's failing. 4.2.2 should be the minimum working version, based on the changelog. maybe it's not reading that version for some reason

Upgrading spotbugs version to 4.8.3 will solve the issue.
